# Can't install cartopy 0.17 with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cartopy, conda-forge

I need to update cartopy 0.16 to 0.17 because of [this bug fix](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1120).

bash command `conda list | grep cartopy` returns:

```
cartopy                   0.16.0
```

When I then do `conda update cartopy`

I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

But then checking again, I still have cartopy 0.16.

I've also tried the commands:

`conda install -c conda-forge cartopy` (that just installs 0.16) and `conda install cartopy=0.17` which takes me through a long list of returns that starts with this:

`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining conflict for conda basemap scipy python mkl_fft twyt...`

But it ultimately doesn't update cartopy.

Does anybody know how I can get the new version *with conda*?

Comment: For people looking at this post with their own problems, I've since managed using `pip install 'cartopy>=0.17'`, but I feel my question about conda still stands because mixing pip and conda is far from ideal.

Comment: Can't reproduce, creating a new environment with cartopy gets me, amongst other things: `cartopy            conda-forge/osx-64::cartopy-0.17.0-py38h4ad5ea1_1011`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are packages in your current env that are conflicting with the newer version of `cartopy`. I suggest creating a seperate environment for that cartopy version:

```
conda create -n <someName> python=<your desired version> cartopy=0.17 <other packages you may need>
```